# Android Studio freeze in fullscreen MAC OSX

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Recently I have problem with Android studio,
in fullscreen mode when plugins or settings window opened or any other pop up window and if I swap with desktop then back again,Android studio will freeze and nothing of pop up windows shows up until I enter Esc to close them or force quit, is there any solution?

Comment: As you've probably discovered, it isn't actually frozen. There's a bug with certain pop-up Windows when running in full screen. While I love full screen, I have been forced to live without it because of this.

Comment: Yeah, this issue is quite annoying.

Comment: Yup, this is an issue for me too! Haven't found a workaround for it other than esc or force quitting and resarting, then staying out of fullscreen!

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio freezes on macOS Big Sur
On machines running macOS Big Sur, Android Studio 4.1 might freeze when you open a dialog.

**To work around this issue, do one of the following:**

Go to the Apple Menu, select System Preferences > General. In the Prefer tabs when opening documents option, select "never". Then restart Android Studio.

source: https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

Answer (score 0):

As Ranjan said, on MacOS Big Sur the config is highlighted
[image: Image showing the configuration]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in the Android Studio 4.2 RC1 preview version, found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview.